# Field-name/ Key validation for io-ts?

Tags: typescript, fp-ts

how do I ensure that the incoming JSON key is valid? I use t.decode, and it didn't throw an error.

```
const UserRequired = t.type({
    firstName : t.string,
    lastName : t.string, 
})

const UserOptional = t.partial({
 
    image : t.string,
})

const User = t.intersection([UserRequired, UserOptional])
```

incoming JSON has a image field but its named imageee. io-ts doesn't throw an error. How to ensure optional check?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't throw an error because you marked `image` as an optional field, so the absence of it doesn't mean that validation should fail.

If you don't want objects with arbitrary fields besides enumerated to pass the validator, you need to wrap it into `t.strict`.

*Side note*: `io-ts` never "throws error", it just returns `Left` object with failed validation data inside. Just in case :)